# Multiple Listeners (Handlers) on Event

Tags: craft3, events

Is it possible to register multiple EventHandlers?

I mean something like this:

```
    Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,[
           NotifyWhenCookPostedArticle::handle,
           RunSomethingElse::handle,
           DeSomethingDifferent::handle
        ]
```

I tried it and got a `PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method`

Is there a notation or helper to get this to work?

Thanks in advance .
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that syntax is possible, and in any case it could get a bit confusing. Why not simply use a single anonymous function and then call your individual handlers inside that e.g.

```
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function(Event $event) {
        $this->NotifyWhenCookPostedArticle();
        $this->RunSomethingElse();
        $this->DoSomethingDifferent();
    }
);

public function NotifyWhenCookPostedArticle() {
    return 'woop';
}
```

(Depending on how separate those things are and/or how large and complex you expect the site to be/become, you would typically abstract them further into your Services layer for reusability and encapsulation).

Comment: Yes you are totally right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a convient solution - so you can do things like that with invokable Classes:

In AppModule.php:

```
Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        new OnEntryAfterSave()
    );
```

In modules\appmodule\Listeners\OnEntryAfterSave.php

```
class OnEntryAfterSave
{
    use Invokable, HasActions;

    protected function actions(): array
    {
        return [
            NotifyWhenCookPostedArticle::class,
            RunSomethingElse::class
        ];
    }

}
```

For this you have to create this two traits:

```
trait Invokable
{
    public function __invoke($args)
    {
        foreach (get_class_methods($this) as $method) {
            if (StringHelper::startsWith($method, 'invoke')) {
                $this->$method($args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was just the setup for using as many invoke functions as you want and extend the class more and more. (just for future thinking - to keep it clean and short)

Then the HasActions trait actually listens for actions to call:

```
trait HasActions
{
    public function invokeActions(ModelEvent $event)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'actions')) {
            foreach ($this->actions() as $action) {
                (new $action)($event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup you can just create a listener class for each CraftEvent to pass.
This class only holds an array of Action Classes to call.

I like it. It's super clean and reuseable.

You can put it into an Abstract Class to extend from. So you end up with something like this:

```
class OnEntryAfterSave extends BaseListener
{

    protected function actions(): array
    {
        return [
            NotifyWhenCookPostedArticle::class,
            RunSomethingElse::class
        ];
    }

}
```

Super slick. ;)